# Using spring cloud data flow , trying to deploy one simple job , but it stuck and deployment not completed

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Following [this](https://www.e4developer.com/2018/02/18/getting-started-with-spring-cloud-data-flow/).

I am trying to deploy one streaming job ,

But job got stuck and never deployed , but in the web UI , it has status "deployed"

```
2018-09-26 17:30:21.817  INFO 83184 --- [nio-9393-exec-5] o.s.c.d.s.s.AppDeployerStreamDeployer    : Deploying application named [file] as part of stream named [Upper-Case-Stream-1] with resource URI [maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:file-sink-rabbit:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
2018-09-26 17:30:22.738  INFO 83184 --- [nio-9393-exec-5] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer       : Deploying app with deploymentId Upper-Case-Stream-1.file instance 0.
   Logs will be in /var/folders/nr/yyxxzlcj1gqfwgbp7mn9l610q3vvqq/T/spring-cloud-dataflow-6132231081394360554/Upper-Case-Stream-1-1537963221817/Upper-Case-Stream-1.file
2018-09-26 17:30:22.747  INFO 83184 --- [nio-9393-exec-5] o.s.c.d.s.s.AppDeployerStreamDeployer    : Deploying application named [transform] as part of stream named [Upper-Case-Stream-1] with resource URI [maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:transform-processor-rabbit:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
2018-09-26 17:30:22.754  INFO 83184 --- [nio-9393-exec-5] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer       : Deploying app with deploymentId Upper-Case-Stream-1.transform instance 0.
   Logs will be in /var/folders/nr/yyxxzlcj1gqfwgbp7mn9l610q3vvqq/T/spring-cloud-dataflow-6132231081394360554/Upper-Case-Stream-1-1537963222747/Upper-Case-Stream-1.transform
2018-09-26 17:30:22.757  INFO 83184 --- [nio-9393-exec-5] o.s.c.d.s.s.AppDeployerStreamDeployer    : Deploying application named [http] as part of stream named [Upper-Case-Stream-1] with resource URI [maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:http-source-rabbit:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
2018-09-26 17:30:22.764  INFO 83184 --- [nio-9393-exec-5] o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer       : Deploying app with deploymentId Upper-Case-Stream-1.http instance 0.
   Logs will be in /var/folders/nr/yyxxzlcj1gqfwgbp7mn9l610q3vvqq/T/spring-cloud-dataflow-6132231081394360554/Upper-Case-Stream-1-1537963222757/Upper-Case-Stream-1.http
```

Comment: Could you please inform what is in the logs of each application? The log above is just the SCDF server, the applications will be in: /var/folders/nr/yyxxzlcj1gqfwgbp7mn9l610q3vvqq/T/spring-cloud-dataflow-6132231081394360554/Upper-Case-Stream-1-1537963221817/Upper-Case-Stream-1.file, /var/folders/nr/yyxxzlcj1gqfwgbp7mn9l610q3vvqq/T/spring-cloud-dataflow-6132231081394360554/Upper-Case-Stream-1-1537963222747/Upper-Case-Stream-1.transform and /var/folders/nr/yyxxzlcj1gqfwgbp7mn9l610q3vvqq/T/spring-cloud-dataflow-6132231081394360554/Upper-Case-Stream-1-1537963222757/Upper-Case-Stream-1.http

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Apps have been deployed, but it is unclear why do you think the stream is in a stuck state.

If the Apps aren't starting successfully, each of the application specific logs will include the details as to why.

Alternatively, when you deploy the stream with [`inheritLogging=true`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.6.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_log_redirect) feature, you'd see all of the application logs as an aggregated output in the server console directly. It'd be a convenient method to debug locally; especially, when you're heavily on development mode.